# Запрос на получение данных если если количество строк превышает заданое

Tags: sql

```
select count(id) from product as p where p.type_id =2;
```

Таким запросом мы посчитаем количество строк,  которые содержат тип 2.

Если мне надо вывести строки, количество которых с типом 2 превышает, скажем, 10, т.е. я знаю, что чтобы вывести все строки с типом 2 надо написать:

`select * from product as p where p.type_id =2;`

Как их выводить, если количество строк превышает 10?

Comment: т.е. выводить где `count(id) > 10`?

Comment: да, т.е. надо посмотреть все строки и если в поле p.type_id   будет больше 10 совпадений то строки с этими совпадениями выведуться

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from product as p where p.type_id =2
and (select count(*) from product p1 where p1.type_id=p.type_id)>10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить условие [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) :

```
select count(id) from product as p 
where p.type_id =2
having count(id) > 10
```

Если надо собрать все строки по любому p.type_id, надо использовать [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
select p.type_id, count(id) from product as p
group by p.type_id
having count(id) > 10
```

Comment: а почему нельзя было добавить еще одно условие в `Where`?

Comment: Потому что where не может использоваться с агрегатными функциями

Comment: а если мне все надо строки проверить и у меня например p.type_id = 3 и 4  5 да чему угодно может ровняться и мне надо по всей таблице пройтись и найти все строки в которых по полю p.type_id  есть более 10 совпадений

Comment: @AlexMur значит надо добавить в вывод Type и GROUP By по нему.

Comment: @AlexMur см апдейт ответа.